# A geometric result involving incentre and excentre

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let ABC is a triangle and $I_c$ and $I_b$ be excentres opposite to vertex C and vertex B respectively. Join A,$I_c$ and $I_b$. The line touches circle again at point Q .We have to prove that Q is the midpoint of line segment $I_bI_c$.I tried to prove but diagram got messy

another interesting result is circumdiameter through Q intersects circle at say P then P is the mid point of minor arc AB.Any help proving the results??

Comment: What is that 'circle'? Are you sure that they are 'touching'?

Comment: @Mick: According to a GeoGebra sketch, OP probably means "The line $I_b A I_c$ *meets* the *circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$* again at point $Q$."

Comment: @Blue My guess is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Yes I forgot.it is circumcircle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the triangle formed by $I_a, I_b, I_c$. $AI_a$ is one of the altidues. The same is true for $BI_b, CI_c$.

[image]

Thus, the circum-circle  is in fact the nine-point circle. It cuts that line at Q and Q by definitiion is the midpoint of $I_bI_c$.

The other fact is ture because $AI_a$ bisects $\angle BAC$.

Comment: +1. Very nice! ...